# How to install angular google maps for an angular 2 app and then import it for typescript?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-google-maps

How to install angular google maps for an angular 2 app and then import it for my typescript component?

Answer (score 1):

one way is including the npm package angular2-google-maps. Or manually include google maps files in your HTML-Page. Then you can use google maps in your components.

- angular2-google-maps https://angular-maps.com/
- Google Maps Tutorial: (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Audience)